# Bootstrap 4 : position relative for img center

Tags: bootstrap-4

I have a problem with the position absolute and relative for the image. And of course to resolve the responsive.

I need to you for helping to me.
This is the screenshot I want
[image]

[this is my jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cyphos/mcsd4e03/7/)

Thanks you a lot

```
<div class="container-fluid text-center">
   <img src="https://img.bfmtv.com/c/630/420/6ea/978bb45ee10aae30b26393fdd58f6.png" class="img-google" />
   <div class="col-sm-12 mx-auto text-center py-5">
      <div class="card text-white">
       <h5 class="card-text" style="padding-bottom: 35px;font-weight: bolder">
        Lorem
      </h5>
      <p class="card-text">
         Le Lorem Ipsum est simplement du faux texte employé dans la composition et la mise en page avant impression. Le Lorem Ipsum est le faux texte standard de l'imprimerie depuis les années 1500, quand un imprimeur anonyme assembla ensemble des morceaux de
    texte pour réaliser.  </p>
       </div>
    </div>
</div>

body {
  padding: 100px 0;
 }

.container-fluid {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #42145F;
 }

.img-google {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 190px;
  width:150px;
}

.card {
  top: 100px;
  background-color: #42145F;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go :

Change:

```
.img-google {
   position: absolute;
   bottom: 190px;
   width: 150px;
 }
```

and

```
.card {
   top: 100px;
   background-color: #42145F;
 }
```

To:

```
.img-google{
    position: relative;
    top: -40px;
    width: 150px;
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
}
.card {
    margin: auto;
    width: 70%;
    background-color: #42145F;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
 }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mcsd4e03/13/

Expln:

1. To make the image center aligned:
     display:block;
     margin:auto;
2. Difference between absolute and relative positioning:
   https://www.lifewire.com/absolute-vs-relative-3466208[1](https://www.lifewire.com/absolute-vs-relative-3466208)
3. To make the text center aligned and white in color:

   text-align:center;
   color:white;

Hope this helps!!

Answer (score 0):

```css
.img-containerz {
        height: 25px;
        text-align: center;
        font: 0/0 a;
    }
     .img-elementz {
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: middle;
        font: 12px/1 open sans Helvetica Neue;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="img-containerz text-center">
     <div class="img-elementz">
      <img class="img-responsive" src="https://img.bfmtv.com/c/630/420/6ea/978bb45ee10aae30b26393fdd58f6.png" style="max-height:50px;z-index:1">
     </div>
       
    </div>
    <div class="card text-white" style="z-index:-1;">
       <h5 class="card-text" style="color:grey">
        Lorem
      </h5>
      <p class="card-text" style="color:grey">
         Le Lorem Ipsum est simplement du faux texte employé dans la composition et la mise en page avant impression. Le Lorem Ipsum est le faux texte standard de l'imprimerie depuis les années 1500, quand un imprimeur anonyme assembla ensemble des morceaux de
    texte pour réaliser.  </p>
       </div>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please Run code snippet it has bs4 and cards too @cyphos

Comment: Thanks you a lot to you all. Good day!!

Comment: Please check it as  the answer so it would be helpful to others too @cyphos